# Deploy Azure form recognizer Invoice in AKS on premise container

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer, on-premises-instances

I have Invoice and Layout services docker images and there is a tutorial on how to deploy it using docker compose [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/containers/form-recognizer-container-install-run?tabs=invoice#tabpanel_1_invoice)

I would like to deploy the same(Invoice & Layout together) in AKS as on-premise. I've tried multiple ways but couldn't get it worked.

If anyone tried deploying above services in on-premise/disconnected environment using kubernetes then please do help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout container hostname has to be same name as this "azure-container-service-layout" and try to deploy in AKS.

In deployment file, make sure below environment variable is **exactly same**. if you change the hostname of layout container(i.e., IP of layout container/localhost/any other hostname) it doesn't forward the request to layout container and Invoice container endpoints will return the failed status since it is depends on layout service([Details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/containers/form-recognizer-container-install-run?tabs=invoice#tabpanel_1_invoice:%7E:text=requirements%20and%20recommendations-,Required%20containers,-The%20following%20table))

*AzureCognitiveServiceLayoutHost=http://azure-cognitive-service-layout:5000*

In deployment file under spec, you can explicitly give static hostname as "azure-cognitive-service-layout".
After adding static hostname to the deployment, I'm able to deploy both containers(layout and invoice) together and get it worked as expected.

```
spec:
  **hostname: azure-cognitive-service-layout**
  containers:
  - name: az-form-recognizer-invoice-deployment
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/form-recognizer/invoice:latest"
```